# cakephp where do I call a global function which each page needs

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I'm using CakePHP (2.2 I think) and am struggling to know where to put a function. It's a function  which is called on each page load. The basic logic is

Page is requested
loads page template
loads included header
 to check if a cookie has been set.
If cookie is set, use values in that
if cookie hasn't been set, load a value from the database and save in the cookie
save cookie values in a config value to use across the page
continue loading page

Basically the function is to set the config values. I have tried to create a helper which worked nicely as I called it on the header view - but as soon as I try to access the cookie helper it didn't work.

I moved the code in to the app controller and called it on the beforefilter() function, but it seems to get called several times on the one page (even though this does actually all work ok).

So - where would I place a function to do this to get called before ANY html is drawn to the screen and is called only once?

Many thanks,
Matt.

Comment: have you tried putting it in the beforeRender function in AppController?

Comment: Yep - that has done the trick thanks! Do you want to add as an answer and I'll make as correct as you did answer first!

Answer (score 1):

`beforeFilter` of your `AppController.php` is the right place. `beforeRender` should also work, as @zynder mentioned.

`beforeFilter` should definitely only be called once per request by Cake. If it's working in `beforeFilter`, but it's being called more than once, you've probably done something wrong, and you should look into that. Or, maybe you could be mistaken in thinking it's executed more than once per request.

Why do you think `beforeFilter` is being called more than once?

Comment: Thanks - I was seeing an error from my beforeFilter() code in three different places on the website. I believe there will be some other problem there as you said. For now, I've put the code in beforeRender which seems to be working nicely. Thank you.